# vue.js external library function calling in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've been long trying to call functions (rewind / fast-forward) in vue.js component here:
https://github.com/phanan/koel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/site-footer/index.vue
i just want to link up the button to call upon the built in 'plyr' function and i just can't seem to make it work. i have been trying for past 4-5 hours, so any hint or help would be much, much appreciated.

All the below resources have their builds running at the url present on main github repo.

(The above componenet calls upon the functions within this playback file.
https://github.com/phanan/koel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/services/playback.js
)

which has associated plyr.js available here:
github.com/Selz/plyr

this is done in js here: (the fast forward / rewind thing) but i just can't get to make it work in vue.js

https://github.com/ableplayer/ableplayer/tree/master/demos

Comment: Please add an answer to your own question (and accept it), or just remove your question.

Comment: how do you access an answer? i have responded with the answer though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done that by calling the event listener on playback. 
after the event listen, calling forward() / Rewind() does the job!